# JS. Поэлементное разбиение множества на подстроки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

есть множество, заданное пользователем, его нужно разбить на элементы, используя регулярные вырежения.
пример:
**{a},b,{a,c,b},{a,{a,b}}**  - множество
**{a} ; b ; {a,c,b}, {a,{a,b}}** - разбитое на элементы множество

Comment: Эм.. Не получится.

Comment: Почему? Например, для этого варианта есть такое решение `([{]+[{,\w]*[}]+)`, но оно не подохдит для `{},x,{{{y}}},{x,{y,z},a}`

Comment: Именно поэтому. Регулярные выражения не умеют скобочные последовательности.

Comment: И вообще, а чем не угодил нормальный вариант?

Comment: Какой,например?

Comment: Просто посчитать уровень вложенности.

Comment: Такое решение поулчается неочень красивым.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript не поддерживает рекурсию в регулярных выражениях, поэтому задачу невозможно решить исключительно регулярными выражениями.

Решение со счетчиком вложенности весьма изящно на самом деле:

```
var repl = (function(m, m1){
  if (typeof(m1)!=="undefined") this.count=0;
  if (m=="{") this.count++;
  else if (m=="}") this.count--;
  else if (m=="," && this.count==0) return "\n";
  return m ;
}).bind({count:0})
var result = "{a},b,{a,c,b},{a,{a,b}}".replace( /(^.)|[{},]/g, repl )
```

Результат (разделенный переносами строк):

```
{a}
b
{a,c,b}
{a,{a,b}}
```

Принцип работы:

1. Все происходит в функции, которая срабатывает на каждое совпадение с регулярным выражением.
2. Если находимся в начале строки, то сбрасываем счетчик
3. Встретив открывающую скобку увеличиваем счетчик
4. Встретив закрывающую скобку - уменьшаем счетчик
5. Встретив запятую при счетчике равном нулю - производим действия для сохранения результата. В данном случае происходит замена запятой на перенос строки

Обработка неправильной грамматики на входе не предусмотрена- не входит в рамки вопроса.